# I'm trying to convert a fasta document into a dictionary in python using a for loop, but only my last iteration gets captured

Tags: python, for-loop, bioinformatics, fasta

I'm trying to write a code to create a dictionary that reads fasta document for a dna sequence, where names of dna sequences are signified with a ">" at the start of the row containing the name. Until the next time a name is encountered, the dna sequence's bases will keep getting assigned to the dictionary entry. The for loop I've created only creates a dictionary for the last sequence, and I can't understand why this happens.

Here's the code I wrote:

```py
def read_fasta():
    with open('../data/problem_1_question_4_new.fasta', 'r') as fasta:
        for line in fasta:
            rows = line.split()
            sequencedict = {}
            sequence = ''
            if str(rows)[2] == '>':
                sequencename = str(rows)[3:-2]
            else:
                sequence += str(rows)[2:-2]
            sequencedict[sequencename] = sequence
    return(sequencedict)
print(read_fasta())
```

I'm assuming that I have an error with the indentations, but I don't know where.

Edit: I've solved the error. I moved the line "sequencedict = {}" outside of the for loop.  My new code is:

```py
def read_fasta():
    with open('../data/problem_1_question_4_new.fasta', 'r') as fasta:
        sequencedict = {}
        for line in fasta:
            rows = line.split()
            sequence = ''
            if str(rows)[2] == '>':
                sequencename = str(rows)[3:-2]
            else:
                sequence += str(rows)[2:-2]
            sequencedict[sequencename] = sequence
    return(sequencedict)
print(read_fasta())
```

Comment: Why *str(rows)* ? Do you really want the string representation of a list?

Comment: You tagged `biopython`, but you're not using it. Why don't you use its built-in FASTA parsing capability?

Comment: @DarkKnight my intention was to gather the list elements in a string, so I attempted to represent the lists in every row as a string before adding the characters I want to the target string "sequence".

Comment: @MattDMo sorry, I'm new to python and the website, so I didn't know biopython was a module. I will edit my post to remove the tag- I can't use the module since it requires me to install it (if I'm not mistaken), and we're supposed to use the built-in functions of base python.

Comment: @ecask No worries. In the future, though, when you're not constrained by assignment limitations, check out https://biopython.org. It's a very useful module for a lot of bioinformatics tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `dict` outside the `for` loop. As it stands, your `dict` is renewed every new iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to look at.  First, you don't want to (re) create the container every iteration of the loop as that undoes the prior work. Secondly, you likely want to add the current item to a key identified list rather than just setting the value of the key as that would capture only the last iteration for any given key.

```py
def read_fasta():
    with open('../data/problem_1_question_4_new.fasta', 'r') as fasta:

        sequencedict = {}  # move creation of the container out of the for loop

        for line in fasta:
            rows = line.split()
            if str(rows)[2] == '>':
                sequencename = str(rows)[3:-2]
                sequence = ''
            else:
                sequence += str(rows)[2:-2]


            sequencedict.setdefault(sequencename, []).append(sequence)  ## append to the right key
    return(sequencedict)
print(read_fasta())
```

If you want to concatenate strings rather than append lists, try:

```py
def read_fasta():
    with open('../data/problem_1_question_4_new.fasta', 'r') as fasta:
        sequencedict = {}  # move creation of the container out of the for loop
        for line in fasta:
            rows = line.split()
            if str(rows)[2] == '>':
                sequencename = str(rows)[3:-2]
                sequence = ''
            else:
                sequence += str(rows)[2:-2]

            sequencedict[sequencename] = sequencedict.get(sequencename, "") + sequence  ## append to the right key

    return(sequencedict)
print(read_fasta())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! When I apply the second change you suggested, though, the resulting dictionary sadly has a format of e.g. {'sequence_01' : ['', 'TATAAGTTTGCAGGTTACCAGGCAATCATTGGGCCTCGCC', 'CAGCAACTTCTAAGGGGCTTCGCTTGACAGCGATCCAATG', 'GCGTCACCTCAGATGGCCTATTATCTGTATTCCTGAAGAG', 'CATTGGTACTGA']}.

Is there any way to make the sequences get appended as strings rather than lists? Thank you.

Comment: the result is still the same :/

Comment: This time there's a SyntaxError: " 'function call' is an illegal expression for augmented assignment "

Comment: I update the answer with what I think should work for concatenation strings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code works, but only after the "+=" command in the "else" block is changed to "+". Since the sequencedict[sequencename] line already expands the sequence with every iteration, the "+=" causes the expansion to happen more for every iteration.

Once again, thank you very much!